# No data importing from Excel to Access with ADO

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, ado

I have a form in Excel that writes to an Excel sheet. In the VBA below, I have requested the cells update an Access database.

There are no errors in uploading the data but **when I go to my access sheet there is no data** present.

**Access table:**  (Click to enlarge)
[image: This is a snip of the access file]

```
Sub Export_Data()
    Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection 
    Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset 
    Dim dbPath, x As Long, i As Long, nextrow As Long

    On Error GoTo errHandler: 'add error handling

    'Variables for file path and last row of data
    dbPath = Sheet19.Range("I3").Value
    nextrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection 'Initialise the collection class variable

    If Sheet18.Range("A2").Value = "" Then  'Check for data
        MsgBox " Add the data that you want to send to MS Access"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    cnn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbPath
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset 'assign memory to the recordset 

    rst.Open Source:="SELECT * FROM [ARF Data Log]", ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
    CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic
    Options = adCmdOpenTable

    'you now have the recordset object; add the values to it
    For x = 2 To nextrow
        rst.AddNew
            For i = 1 To 29
                rst(Cells(1, i).Value) = Cells(x, i).Value
            Next i
        rst.Update
    Next x

    rst.Close         'close the recordset
    cnn.Close         'close the connection
    Set rst = Nothing 'clear memory
    Set cnn = Nothing

    'communicate with the user
    MsgBox " The data has been successfully sent to the access database"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True  'Update the sheet
    Sheet19.Range("h7").Value = Sheet19.Range("h8").Value + 1 'show the next ID
    Sheet18.Range("A2:ac1000").ClearContents  'Clear the data
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
errHandler:

    Set rst = Nothing  'clear memory
    Set cnn = Nothing
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in Export_Data"
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you add the lines `Debug.Print "Adding: " & rst.Supports(adAddNew)` and `Debug.Print "Update: " & rst.Supports(adUpdate)` just before the loop? I'd be interested to see what it tells us.

Comment: you haven't mentioned a worksheet on the line adding the data. Is there only one open?

Comment: @Inarion I added     `Debug.Print "Adding: " & rst.Supports(adAddNew) and Debug.Print "Update: " & rst.Supports(adUpdate)` but it still says the data has been successfully imported

Comment: @ashleedawg there are 19 worksheets in the workbook, i'm sorry but I don't know how to specify the data to worksheet 18?

Comment: Yes, the question is: What does the immediate window (`Ctrl+G`) tell you?

Comment: @Inarion it says; adding: True     Update: True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the fields you are updating. This is either done with `!` or with `.Fields`. If you do not specify, you could use the index of the column.

**- With `!`**

---

```
Sub DataPopulation()

    Dim myConn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim DBS As ADODB.Recordset

    Set myConn = CurrentProject.Connection
    Set DBS = New ADODB.Recordset

    DBS.Open "SomeDB", myConn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

    DBS.AddNew
    DBS!StudentNumber = 1
    DBS!StudentName = "SomeName"
    DBS!Grade = 10

    DBS.AddNew
    DBS!StudentNumber = 2
    DBS!StudentName = "SomeFamilyName"
    DBS!Grade = 10

    DBS.Update
    DBS.Close

    Set DBS = Nothing
    Set myConn = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

**- With `.Fields`:**

---

```
Do While Len(Range("A" & r).Formula) > 0
    With rs
        .AddNew
        .Fields("Commodity #") = Range("A" & r).Value
        .Update
    End With
    r = r + 1   
Loop
```

---

**- With Index:** If you use the numerical index of the fields, then they start from 1 to the count of the fields. In your case `rst(i)` should be ok, if you have at least `i` columns. In the example below, there are 3 columns available:

---

```
For tblRow = 1 To 10
    DBS.AddNew
    For tblCol = 1 To 3
        DBS(tblCol) = "Row: " & tblRow & " Col: " & tblCol
    Next
Next
```

[image]

Comment: It's also possible (less specific and more prone to error, though) to address fields by their numerical index.

Comment: Hi @Vityata i have edited the code to the index format. It works "Adding: True
Update: True" but there is no data in the access file. The code is below  `For x = 2 To nextrow
rst.AddNew
For i = 1 To 29
rst(i) = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet18").Cells(x, i).Value
Next i
rst.Update
Next x`

Comment: @Joji5566 - try again trying to write `1` instead to read the data from the worksheet. If it is ok, then the problem is that the correct worksheet is not referred.

Comment: @Joji5566 The tests for `rst.Supports(adAddNew)` and `rst.Supports(adUpdate)` were just necessary once to see if the DB will generally let you write data to that recordset. It doesn't tell you whether it *actually succeeded* in doing so. As such, it has no bearing on Vityata's attempts at a solution and I think you can remove those 2 lines from your code.

Comment: @vityata I tried it as rst(i) = "1". No data seems to have transferred. I guess im not referring the correct access worksheet - the name of the table is "ARF Data Log" and the database path is correct

Comment: @Joji5566 - strange. If you are using hardcoded data, then it should be transferred...

Comment: Thank you again for your help. Clearly there is something lacking in my knowledge. I'm going to retry it again with this [link](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=excel+to+access+ado&oq=excel+to+access+ado&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j0l2.8860j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and the knowledge you have shared with me :)

Comment: @Joji5566 - you are welcome :) Controlling Excel from Access and Access from Excel with VBA is really a piece of a worthy knowledge, which would pay back every invested minute in it. Good luck!